# Duplicates in Listbox when displaying items from a List<T>. Please help!

Tags: c#, list, listbox

I got a List that I add to every time I create a new Employee.
The content of this list is then displayed in a Listbox. The problem is that each time
I add a new Employee and then call the below method the items in the listbox gets duplicated over and over again. So if I got 3 items in the list the Listbox displays 6.
I have checked with employeeList.Count and I am sure about the amount of items in the list.

What is wrong?

```
public void UpdateEmployeeList()
{
    foreach (Employees values in employeeRegistry.employeerList)
    {
       lstResults.Items.Add(values);
    }
}
```

Thankful for all help!

Comment: Does the listbox show duplicate employees as abcabc or aabbcc? May be you have set the datasource property already in the list box, and you are updating manually again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you Clear your listbox before adding new employees ?

```
public void UpdateEmployeeList()
{
    lstResults.Items.Clear();
    foreach (Employees values in employeeRegistry.employeerList)
    {
       lstResults.Items.Add(values);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always add all employees, you must first clear the items:

```
lstResults.Items.Clear();
```

or better only add the new one...